# Powershell script to check folder/subfolder

Tags: powershell, email

Trying to figure out a powershell script to loop though a directory and send an email every 15 minutes with a list of files uploaded into the directory. Schedule task will run throughout the day

Email subject must contain a list of file and a path were it was uploaded to

Example:

- TEST.TXT uploaded to C:\ROOT\BUSINESS\
- test2.txt uploaded to  C:\ROOT\BUSINESS\May2021

Directory = Business
Inside of Business will have multiple subfolders
May2021
June2021
July2021

Files will be dropped every day on the root and subfolders

```
$SMTPServer = "EMAIL SERVER (ip)"
$SMTPPort = "111"
$Username = "SENDER@EMAIL.COM"
$path="C:\ROOT\BUSINESS\"

$to = "test1@gmail.com"
$cc = "test2@gmail.com"
$subject = " New File available "
$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$message.subject = $subject
$message.to.add($to)
$message.cc.add($cc)
$message.from = $username

$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);
$smtp.EnableSSL = $true
#$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential $Username;

If ($File = Get-ChildItem $Path | Where { $_.LastWriteTime -ge [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-15) }){
$smtp.send($message)}
write-host "Mail Sent"
```

Comment: Running the task every 15 minutes instead of a loop that will run for the entire day will save you lots of troubles.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon thanks, any idea how i could build on this script ?

Comment: Task Scheduler.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon How could I get a list of files after running A schedule task every 15 minutes ? I do not want 20 different emails, one 1 email with a list of 20 files should be enough